# Optimizing a Free Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, free-monad, scala-cats, recursion-schemes

If I have a value `a: Free[Op, A]`, is it possible to "flatten" the structure of `a` so that two `Op`s that are bound together by the free monad may be collapsed into one?

*Context:* I'd like to perform this as an optimization step before interpretation because a semantic of `Op` is that its operations are idempotent. So if two appear "in a row", the second can be eliminated at no cost to the semantics of the program.

Comment: Maybe this can only be done at the interpreter level? It seems like a useful generalization to have.

Comment: It's an Scalaz/cats implementation constraint stemming from Scala's eager evaluation strategy rather than fundamental Free limitation. Reason is Gosub/FlatMapped constructor used by `Free`'s `flatMap` to prevent stack overflow: it makes further introspection progress impossible by wrapping a computation into trampoline function.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand there is no way for this kind introspection of  Free Monad program as it represents sequential computation where each step depends on the result of another.

There is a great talk by John de Goes about the pros and cons of Free Monad vs Free Applicative (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H28QqxO7Ihc). The latter gives power of introspection.