# Is it possible to optimise a Free Monad program before execution?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, free-monad

I've recently picked up the Free Monad pattern using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html) in an attempt to create a DSL which can be "simplified" before execution. For example, let's say I create a language for interacting with lists:

```
  sealed trait ListAction[A]
  case class ListFilter[A](in: List[A], p: A => Boolean) extends ListAction[List[A]]
  case class ListMap[A, B](in: List[A], f: A => B) extends ListAction[List[B]]

  type ListProgram[A] = Free[ListAction, A]
```

Before executing any program built with these actions, I want to optimise it by transforming subsequent filters into a single filter and transforming subsequent maps into a single map in order to avoid iterating over the list multiple times:

```
// Pseudo code - doesn't compile, just illustrates my intent

def optimise[A](program: ListProgram[A]): ListProgram[A] = {
  case ListFilter(ListFilter(in, p1), p2) => optimise(ListFilter(in, { a: A => p1(a) && p2(a) }))
  case ListMap(ListMap(in, f1), f2) => optimise(ListMap(in, f2 compose f1))
}
```

Is this possible using the Free Monad, either by inspecting the last action when adding to the program or by optimising as above? Thanks very much.

---

Below is the code I've been using to create my programs:

```
  trait ListProgramSyntax[A] {
    def program: ListProgram[List[A]]

    def listFilter(p: A => Boolean): ListProgram[List[A]] = {
      program.flatMap { list: List[A] =>
        Free.liftF[ListAction, List[A]](ListFilter(list, p))
      }
    }

    def listMap[B](f: A => B): ListProgram[List[B]] = program.flatMap { list =>
      Free.liftF(ListMap(list, f))
    }
  }

  implicit def syntaxFromList[A](list: List[A]): ListProgramSyntax[A] = {
    new ListProgramSyntax[A] {
      override def program: ListProgram[List[A]] = Free.pure(list)
    }
  }

  implicit def syntaxFromProgram[A](existingProgram: ListProgram[List[A]]): ListProgramSyntax[A] = {
    new ListProgramSyntax[A] {
      override def program: ListProgram[List[A]] = existingProgram
    }
  }
```

For example:

```
  val program = (1 to 5).toList
    .listMap(_ + 1)
    .listMap(_ + 1)
    .listFilter(_ % 3 == 0)
```

---

**EDIT**: After my colleague searched for "Free Monad optimize" using the American spelling we found [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794492/optimizing-a-free-monad) to this question asserting it is not possible to do this *before* interpretation.

However, it must surely be possible to interpret the program to produce an optimised version of it and then interpret that to retrieve our `List[A]`?

Comment: "*it must surely be possible to interpret the program to produce an optimised version of it*" - how is that "before execution"? The point is that you cannot interpret `flatMap` without calling the function.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. I will explore other tools to achieve what I want. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get what I want by just defining my "program" structure in a recursive ADT:

```
  sealed trait ListAction[A]
  case class ListPure[A](list: List[A]) extends ListAction[A]
  case class ListFilter[A](previous: ListAction[A], p: A => Boolean) extends ListAction[A]
  case class ListMap[A, B](previous: ListAction[A], f: A => B) extends ListAction[B]

  trait ListActionSyntax[A] {
    def previousAction: ListAction[A]

    def listFilter(p: A => Boolean): ListFilter[A] = ListFilter(previousAction, p)

    def listMap[B](f: A => B): ListMap[A, B] = ListMap(previousAction, f)
  }

  implicit def syntaxFromList[A](list: List[A]): ListActionSyntax[A] = {
    new ListActionSyntax[A] {
      override def previousAction: ListAction[A] = ListPure(list)
    }
  }

  implicit def syntaxFromProgram[A](existingProgram: ListAction[A]): ListActionSyntax[A] = {
    new ListActionSyntax[A] {
      override def previousAction: ListAction[A] = existingProgram
    }
  }

  def optimiseListAction[A](action: ListAction[A]): ListAction[A] = {
    def trampolinedOptimise[A](action: ListAction[A]): Eval[ListAction[A]] = {
      action match {

        case ListFilter(ListFilter(previous, p1), p2) =>
          Eval.later {
            ListFilter(previous, { e: A => p1(e) && p2(e) })
          }.flatMap(trampolinedOptimise(_))

        case ListMap(ListMap(previous, f1), f2) =>
          Eval.later {
              ListMap(previous, f2 compose f1)
          }.flatMap(trampolinedOptimise(_))

        case ListFilter(previous, p) =>
          Eval.defer(trampolinedOptimise(previous)).map { optimisedPrevious =>
            ListFilter(optimisedPrevious, p)
          }

        case ListMap(previous, f) =>
          Eval.defer(trampolinedOptimise(previous)).map { optimisedPrevious =>
            ListMap(optimisedPrevious, f)
          }

        case pure: ListPure[A] => Eval.now(pure)
      }
    }

    trampolinedOptimise(action).value
  }

  def executeListAction[A](action: ListAction[A]): List[A] = {
    def trampolinedExecute[A](action: ListAction[A]): Eval[List[A]] = {
      action match {
        case ListPure(list) =>
          Eval.now(list)

        case ListMap(previous, f) =>
          Eval.defer(trampolinedExecute(previous)).map { list =>
            list.map(f)
          }

        case ListFilter(previous, p) =>
          Eval.defer(trampolinedExecute(previous)).map { list =>
            list.filter(p)
          }
      }
    }

    trampolinedExecute(action).value
  }
```

This has the downside that I don't get stack-safety for free and have to ensure my optimisation and execution methods are properly trampolined.